# Shaky scrollTop and scrollLeft

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop, mousemove

I am trying to enable the user to move a page vertically and horizontally using the mouse. To do that, I use jQuery's scrollTop() and scrollLeft() functions to scroll the document when the user press and move the mouse. My code works fine but the page shakes strongly while it's moving.
I have been able to generate the same problem with a smaller piece of code.
Here is a [live demo](http://testhtmlfiles.co.nf/test1.html).
Any ideas what causes this shaky behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this for your jQuery. Here is a working [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/MeQML/)

```
var down=false;
var downX=0;
var downY=0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mousedown(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        down=true;
        downX=e.clientX;
        downY=e.clientY;
        return false;
    }).mouseup(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        down=false;
        return false;
    }).mousemove(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(down){
            $(document).scrollTop($(document).scrollTop()-e.clientY+downY)
                .scrollLeft($(document).scrollLeft()-e.clientX+downX);
            downY = e.clientY; //Reset the cursor's last Y position
            downX = e.clientX; //Reset the cursor's last X position
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

This was adapted from the [**draggable.js**](https://code.google.com/p/albireo/source/browse/trunk/AlbireoIS/document_root/js/libs/dragscrollable.js?r=441&spec=svn441) jQuery pluggin. I highly recommend you use it. It does all of this work for you. Here is a demo of it http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/scrollpane.html.

Comment: Yep, that should do it!

Comment: Thanks, your code works perfectly. I've just tried to use clientX and clientY instead of pageX and pageY, without changing anything else in my code and it also worked without problems.

Answer (score 1):

You're 'flapping'. If you put a breakpoint at line 134 and watch the relevant values, you can see it happen:

- $(document).scrollTop()
- downScrollTop
- Math.floor(e.pageY-downY)

Drag the text once to start the cycle, then watch them loop as you advance through the breakpoints. Your alteration of scrollTop and scrollLeft is triggering a mousemove event. I'm not sure it will do that in all browsers, but it clearly does in Chrome.